# iptables rules - Forward/Masquerade sevices using nat table

Tags: networking, iptables, nat, ipv4, dnat

I need to complete an exercise with `iptables` on a network (docker containers) configured as follows:

1. A `router` host with 2 network interfaces (`eth0 <- public 10.9.0.0/24`; `eth1 <- lan 192.168.60.0/24`; the `router` is the `x.x.x.254` on both networks) and an SSH server on default port 22;
2. A `jumpbox` host in `lan` with IP `192.168.60.10`, with SSH and TELNET on default ports 22 and 23;
3. An `admin` host in `public` with IP `10.9.0.2`.

One of the requests made to us is the forwarding/masquerade of the SSH (on port 2222) and TELNET services of the `jumbox` host via the `router` to the `admin` host.
The problem is that I can't redirect these ports, the connection remains on perpetual hold (I think because the return packets are not configured correctly).
Currently my configuration is as follows (see `ADMIN'S RULES`):

```shell
#!/bin/bash

# Reset IPv4 rules
iptables -t filter -F
iptables -t filter -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X

# Set default policies for chains
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# Allow loopback traffic
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow traffic for ongoing connections
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT


# ====================== #
#  NAT INTERNAL NETWORK  #
# ====================== #

# Masquerade internal network hosts
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.60.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

# Forward internal network requests to external network
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT


# =============== #
#  ADMIN'S RULES  #
# =============== #

# Allow 'admin' connection to 'jumpbox' SSH (on 2222 port)
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.60.10 -p tcp --sport 22   -j SNAT --to 10.9.0.254:2222
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -s 10.9.0.2      -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to 192.168.60.10:22
iptables        -A FORWARD     -s 10.9.0.2      -p tcp --dport 22   -j ACCEPT

# Allow 'admin' connection to 'jumpbox' TELNET
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.60.10 -p tcp --sport 23 -j SNAT --to 10.9.0.254
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -s 10.9.0.2      -p tcp --dport 23 -j DNAT --to 192.168.60.10
iptables        -A FORWARD     -s 10.9.0.2      -p tcp --dport 23 -j ACCEPT
```

Could someone please direct me to the solution?
Thanks in advance.

---

#### EDIT:

After several attempts I succeeded in my intent with these commands:

```shell
# Allow 'admin' connection to 'jumpbox' SSH (on 2222 port)
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -s 10.9.0.2 -d 10.9.0.254    -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT   --to 192.168.60.10:22
iptables        -A FORWARD     -s 10.9.0.2 -d 192.168.60.10 -p tcp --dport 22   -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING             -d 192.168.60.10 -p tcp --dport 22   -j SNAT   --to 192.168.60.254

# Allow 'admin' connection to 'jumpbox' TELNET
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -s 10.9.0.2 -d 10.9.0.254    -p tcp --dport 23 -j DNAT   --to 192.168.60.10
iptables        -A FORWARD     -s 10.9.0.2 -d 192.168.60.10 -p tcp --dport 23 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING             -d 192.168.60.10 -p tcp --dport 23 -j SNAT   --to 192.168.60.254
```

Now the problem becomes that if I try to connect using the internal IP:

```shell
$ telnet 192.168.60.10 23  # or
$ ssh -p2222 192.168.60.10
```

I am able to do this, but **I have to block this behavior**.

Comment: The `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` on the `router` is set.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve my goal with the following rules:

```shell
# ...

# Allow 'admin' connection to 'jumpbox' SSH (on 2222 port)
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -s 10.9.0.2 -d 10.9.0.254                                -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT   --to 192.168.60.10:22
iptables        -A FORWARD     -s 10.9.0.2 -d 192.168.60.10 -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -p tcp --dport 22   -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING             -d 192.168.60.10                             -p tcp --dport 22   -j SNAT   --to 192.168.60.254

# Allow 'admin' connection to 'jumpbox' TELNET
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -s 10.9.0.2 -d 10.9.0.254                                -p tcp --dport 23 -j DNAT   --to 192.168.60.10
iptables        -A FORWARD     -s 10.9.0.2 -d 192.168.60.10 -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -p tcp --dport 23 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING             -d 192.168.60.10                             -p tcp --dport 23 -j SNAT   --to 192.168.60.254
```